# Move/Animate Div with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, move

I want to move a `div` using javascript.

For example, how would I move a `div` to the left 50px using javascript?

I want the function to start when after I click on a link. Anyone know how this could be done?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You might want to check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Formatting your question correctly will go a long way to getting you the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that works:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <span id="box"></span>
</div>
<a href="#" id="move-test">Move test element.</a>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: beige;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Javascript:Please put this within the document ready function.

```
$("#move-test").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    moveBox();
});

var moveBox = function(){
    var $box = $("#box");
    var left = $box.position().left;
    left = left - 20;
    $box.css('left', left + 'px');
};
```

Here is a jsfiddle with it moving continuously:

https://jsfiddle.net/5ncb6szg/

Comment: Please upvote if you liked my response since I also just joined stackoverflow today!

Comment: So the thing is, I'm making a contact page. Right now I made the div box for it super far to the right so no one can see it, like 10000px to the right, and when I click on the link "contact", i want it to come back. I have this:

Comment: <a href="javascript:movecontact()"><h3 id="contact">Contact</div>

Comment: and Im trying to figure out the javascript, I have this: 

var movecontact = document.getElementById("contactpage");



function popup() {
 movecontact.style.left = '100px'; 
}

Comment: Ideally its better to move it far left rather than far right. and in such a case just modify above code to do this:  $box.css('left', '0px'); Why dont you try it in jsfiddle and post it here, that way its easier to fix.

Comment: How come this doesn't work? Sorry for the dumb questions. http://jsfiddle.net/xcra0k2t/

Comment: Okay, Thank you. I guessed that to be the case after the above conversation and have posted a pure javascript solution above.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `position: relative` as negative margins are frowned upon. Set the default to `left: -100%` which means that the element should be moved left the same amount as it is wide. For the javascript we assign a click handler to the link in the script instead of inline. Assign the variable `open=false` because it is closed on first load, then when we open it assign the variable to `open=true`. This gives state to the element without querying the dom.

```js
var hidden = true;
var box = document.getElementById("box");
document.getElementById('toggle').onclick = function() {
    if(hidden) hidden = false, box.style.left = 0; 
    else hidden = true, box.style.left = '-100%';
}
```

```css
#box {
    background: red;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
    left: -100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="toggle">
  <h3 id="contact">Contact</h3>
</a>
<div id="box"></div>
```